# Нужно ли обнулять указатель после использования оператора delete?

Tags: c++, указатели, память

Нужно ли обнулять указатель после использования оператора `delete`? Или же он, в отличие от функции `malloc`, обнуляет указатель самостоятельно?

```
int *v = new int(5);
delete v;
v = nullptr;
```

И что насчет удаления указателя в следующем коде:

```
(1) int *a = new int[10];
(2) delete [] a;
(3) delete a;
(4) a = nullptr;
```

Нужно ли удалять указатель, как в третьей строчке? Если нет, то я так понимаю, что необходимо его обнулить, как в четвертой?

Comment: delete освобождает область памяти, которую ты выделил ранее через new, а сам указатель после освобождения памяти будет указывать на какую-нибудь ячейку рандомную

Comment: @bsuart2017, нет, не рандомную. В оперативной памяти есть вполне определенный (в контексте конкретной ОС) диапазон, который зарезервирован ОС и недоступен пользователю - так вот  этот самый диапазон и используется для выявления нулевых указателей.

Comment: @isnullxbh, да есть определенный диапазон, но в данном контексте вопроса не было смысла объяснять,на какую конкретно ячейку будет указывать указатель, это уже совсем отдельный вопрос и тема

Comment: @bsuart2017, так если этого не было в вопросе, зачем же Вы добавили вот это: "..а сам указатель после освобождения памяти будет указывать на какую-нибудь ячейку рандомную." ? Ведь Вас об этом не спрашивали. Теперь я объясню, почему я сделал Вам замечание: Вы же не станете отрицать, что после того, как указатель стал указывать на "рандомную" ячейку, в этой ячейке могло быть что-то такое, что не вызвало бы UB, SF и т.д. при разыменовании указателя ? А это уже как-то нехорошо, Вам не кажется ?

Comment: @isnullxbh, не понимаю в чем собственно проблема. Я не давал ответ на текущий вопрос, а просто сделал комментарий, так как знал, что развернутый ответ кто-то даст со всеми объяснениями. Согласен, что мой комментарий не совсем корректный, потому что это действительно не рандомная ячейка, с Вашим замечанием согласен.

Comment: @bsuart2017, нет, никакой проблемы нет, и после Вашего последнего комментария не осталось и намека на нее.

Comment: @bsuart2017, что такое UB, понятно. А что такое SF?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Данный код имеет неопределенное поведение, так как имеет место попытка дважды удалить память, адресуемую указателем `a`, причем во второй раз используется неверный оператор удаления.

```
int *a = new int[10];
delete [] a;
delete a;
a = nullptr;
```

Обычно советуют обнулять указатель после освобождения указываемой им памяти, чтобы при повторной попытке удаления памяти не возникла ошибка выполнения программы. Например, данный код корректен

```
int *a = new int[10];
//...
delete [] a;
a = nullptr;
//...
delete [] a;
```

так как можно вызывать операторы `delete` и `delete[]` для `null`-указателей.

Однако тем самым вы маскируете потенциальную ошибку в вашей программе. Возможно, что ваша программа работает неправильно и, действительно, пытается по крайней мере дважды удалить ту же самую область память. Если вы присвоите указателю значение `nullptr`, то  вам будет сложно обнаружить данную ошибку.

Аргумент в пользу присваивания значения `nullptr` состоит в том, что если у вас указатель равен `nullptr`, то вам будет легко обнаружить попытку обращения к памяти с использованием этого указателя. Однако на самом деле это не всегда так. Например, операционная система `z/OS` на `IBM mainframe` позволяет читать память, используя null-указатель. Она лишь не разрешает записывать данные по такому указателю. Поэтому, опять-таки, присваивая значение `nullptr` указателю, вы можете замаскировать ошибку, когда вы будете обращаться к памяти на чтение по нулевому адресу. По-моему опыту такую ошибку часто совершают C программисты, работающие на `IBM mainfarme`, когда используют стандартные строковые функции из библиотеки `<string.h>` , вызывая, например, функцию сравнения строк `strcmp`, когда один из указателей равен `NULL`.  В результате программа имеет неопределенное поведение. Но обнаружить такую ошибку очень сложно.

С другой стороны явное присваивание указателю значения `nullptr` способствует самодокументированию исходного кода. Читателю дается знать, что, начина с этого присваивания, указатель является недействительным.

Так что универсального правила нет. Желательно делать так, чтобы время жизни переменной, обозначающей указатель, совпадало с временем жизни памяти, на которую он указывает. В этом случае нет никакого смысла присваивать указателю значение `nullptr` , так как указатель прекращает свое существование одновременно с удалением адресуемой им памятью.

Чаще всего вы можете встретить код, где используется либо инициализация указателя нулем, либо присвоения ему null-значения в старых C программах, так как ранее, до принятия стандарта C99, переменные можно было объявлять только в начале блоков кода. Поэтому между объявлением указателя и его использованием или между удалением памяти, адресуемой указателем, и прекращением жизни самого указателя очень часто имелось много строк кода, которые трудно охватить одним взором исходного текста.  Поэтому присвоение указателям значения `NULL`, позволяло читающим код  легче разобраться в логике работы той или иной громоздкой функции.

В настоящее время вы как в C, так и в C++ можете объявлять переменные в любом месте блока кода, а потому можете сужать время жизни переменных до той части кода, где они непосредственно используются. А потому большой надобности присваивать нулевого значения "отработавшему" указателю уже нет.

Старайтесь объявлять переменные в наименьшей области объявления там, где они непосредственно используются. чтобы не было "подвисших" переменных, о которых нельзя сказать, используются ли они еще где-либо в коде, или они уже больше не используются.

Кроме того в C++ есть так называемые умные указатели, а также соответствующие контейнеры, которые сами заботятся об удаление уже не используемой памяти. Выделение и удаление памяти "вручную" чревато возникновению ошибок в программе.

Answer (score 12):

Давайте будем отличать указатель, и данные, на которые он указывает.

Оператор `delete` работает с памятью, *на которую* указывает указатель. При этом если вы выделяли память при помощи `new`, то освобождать нужно при помощи `delete`. А если при помощи `new[...]`, то освобождать нужно при помощи `delete[]`. (Ответственность за это лежит на вас.)

Оператор `delete` не меняет указатель, но он после `delete` указывает на невалидную память (скорее всего, эта память будет распределена ещё кому-нибудь под его цели). Имеет смысл самостоятельно присвоить значение `nullptr` указателю после `delete`, чтобы не использовать случайно невалидную память. Но это не обязательно и скорее предосторожность для вас, а не требование языка.

Требование языка только одно: после `delete` вы не должны обращаться к отданной системе памяти по указателю. Как вы это обеспечите — полностью ваша забота.

Да, и второй раз удалять объект по указателю нельзя! Потому что вообще нельзя обращаться к удалённой памяти (попытка удаления — это тоже обращение). Поэтому строка `(3)` неправильна с двух сторон: это повторное удаление памяти, которое запрещено, и удаление без `[]`, хотя память была выделена с `[]`.

Answer (score 6):

С указателем вы можете делать что хотите :) `delete` с самой переменной не делает ничего. Можете ее обнулить, можете - нет, но тогда просто помните, что он теперь указывает непонятно куда, и использовать это значение больше нельзя.

В вашем примере корректно удалять так, как в строке 2.

(Шепотом: для `int`, правда, из-за отсутствия дестркуторов сойдет и третий способ... но в общем случае это ошибка! Шепотом - чтобы никто не воспринял это как разрешение поступать таким образом :) Я просто упомянул об этом, но *настаиваю на том, чтобы так не поступать ни в коем случае!*)

Строка 4 - на ваше усмотрение...

Comment: Про инт можно поподробнее?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, у простых типов нет деструкторов.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Ну, вам уже все рассказали :) Именно - когда нечего вызывать, `delete` просто освобождает память. **Теоретически** `new[] ` и `new` - это разные операции, так что `delete` там, где нужен `delete[]`, может привести к проблемам... но пока я не слышал о компиляторе, который бы к ним реально приводил для фундаментальных типов. Впрочем, в любом случае лично я *категорически не рекомендую* так поступать... Сейчас усилю в ответе этот момент :)

Comment: @Harry, я всегда думал, что `delete` удаляет один элемент заданного типа, а `delete[]` каким зависимым от реализации способом определяет колличество элементов и освобождает их все.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb     `int * s = new int[50];
    printf("%p\n",s);
    delete s;
    s = new int[50];
    printf("%p\n",s);` дает (VC++) `0056E4C0
0056E4C0` - т.е. *вся* память реально освобождена и выделена опять. Но, конечно, я не стану класть никакие части тела на колоду :), что это пройдет всегда и везде.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, все известные мне реализации используют банальные `malloc`/`free`, которые не в состоянии отличить один элемент от множества, поэтому, на практике память должна освобождаться корректно. Это не отменяет того, что само такое применение является UB.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Кстати, из-за этого `malloc`/`free` сработает даже `free(new int)` - но опять же, поступать так, конечно же, не стоит...

Comment: @Harry, нашел эту тему в [C++ Super-FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-array-built-ins)

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Ну правильно, нельзя. Но в военное время, как говорится, прямой угол доходит до 100 градусов :) Т.е. есть perfect C++, а есть - imperfect C++, как называлась одна очень интересная книга, где говорилось о том, как на самом деле устроены те или иные компиляторы (жаль, очень уж старенькая). Сейчас глянул исходники Open Watcom  - там четко `delete[]` вызывает просто `delete`. Других исходников нет, но тестдрайв на VC++ я показал...

Answer (score 1):

*Вот что написано в умной книге..* Когда оператор `delete` применяется к указателю, освобождается область динамической памяти, на которую он указывает. Повторное применение оператора `delete` к этому же указателю приведет к зависанию программы. При освобождении области динамической памяти рекомендуется присваивать связанному с ней указателю нулевое значение (0). Вызов оператора `delete` для нулевого указателя пройдет совершенно безболезненно для программы. Пример:

```
Animal *pDog = new Animal;
delete pDog; // освобождение динамической памяти
pDog = 0; // присвоение указателю нулевого значения
delete pDog; // вполне безопасно
```

**ps**
книга по стандарту 98 года.

Comment: Именно к зависанию - вряд ли. К UB - да. Причем это UB может использоваться даже для взлома.

Comment: @Harry ub ведет с очень большим процентом к зависанию программы.

Comment: По-моему, куда скорее к аварийному завершению, а не к зависанию.

Comment: @Harry если быть точней зависит от самой программы. если там много циклов (а это большинство программ) то вероятность создания бесконечного цикла очень велика. а вообще du может проявить себя вообще в другой программе или даже в самой ОС (в том числе и подвесить их).

Comment: @Harry , а если программа вылетела с сообщением то с большой долей уверенности могу сказать что это не du а системный перехват.

Comment: @perfect В другой программе проявить это как? По дефолту операционка разделяет память для процессов же.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian , вы сейчас пытаетесь предугадать BU) ? Как же хакеры проникают в чужие процессы?

Comment: @perfect что-то мне подсказывает, что не с помощью `delete` над невалидными указателями. Впрочем, какая-то мизерная вероятность все же есть.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian , достаточно подменить хандлер (если это виндовс) и делай с чужой программой что хочешь. после того как я неожиданно для себя с помощи делфи получил все изображения экрана из видеобуфера я теперь этому не удивлюсь нисколько.

Comment: @perfect речь ведь идет о некорректном использовании delete, а не о целенаправленном вмешательстве в работу другой программы. Вряд ли ошибочный delete даст вам изображение экрана.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian , я вам сейчас пытаюсь сказать что к памяти можно получить прямой доступ и что то удалить из нее.